Sheaf of differentials with log poles
Is the sheaf of log differentials along a divisor $D$ isomorphic to the sheaf of p-forms times the sheaf associated to the divisor $D$? In other words is the following an isomorphism: $\Omega^p_X(\log D) \cong \Omega^p_X \otimes \mathcal{O}_X(D)$?

Why do you think this to be true?

"is the following" - you have not defined the following!

@FShrike This refers to the equation on the next line. OP: The answer is no, even if the divisor happens to be locally irreducible. Don't you have an actual definition? (Note, for example, that $dz_2/z_1$ is not a holomorphic multiple of $dz_1/z_1$.)

@TedShifrin no of course it does, it’s just not a defined thing. “Is $A\cong B$ an isomorphism?”
